# Create dynamic pages from search results

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am calling a SQL search query and based on the number of results, generate pages with a set amount of results on each page. I want to be able to generate a drop-down menu to select which page to navigate to.

How would I go about doing this using javascript and cookies? Any help pointing me to the right direction would be great. (links to code, or examples)

Thanks =]

Comment: thanks, i didnt know how to use this =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want all the paging to be client-sided? That is: Load each and every entry to the browser and paginate them with javascript?

If not, the paging code is actually server-sided and, probably, not javascript... It would be a matter of keeping reference to the page and sending the parameters to the server.

At all cases, take a look at this: http://www.trirand.com/blog/.

jqgrid (along with jquery) is a great tool and will help you a lot in implementing pagination (client or server sided)